# How to secure tomcat manager for multiple instances

Tags: security, tomcat

I have multiple instances of Tomcat setup using the CATALINA_BASE method.

I need to enable the tomcat manager application for each of them, and to secure them all separately based on groups of users.

I have a manager.xml setup under the BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost location for each instance, pointing to the webapps location of the CATALINA_HOME install. This shares the app amongst all the instances.

It looks to me like the web.xml file is the location to modify the security constraints based on username or group.

How to I define a specific security constraint based on which instance I am using, instead of letting all valid users have access to all instances? Do I need to install the manager app under all instances or is there another method I can use?

Comment: Multiple instances of Tomcat is that you have installed the complete tomcat on different locations, or are you talking about many applications deployed in a single Tomcat? BTW - which Tomcat-version are you talking about?

Comment: Multiple instances of CATALINA_BASE locations, all pointing to the same CATALINA_HOME as the code base. So each instance is separate, just using the same base code.

Version 7.0.27